# Adding dynamic variable to an Angular method does not seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I bet this has something to do with events binding after the variables are instantiated.

But suppose I have something like this :

```
%li{'ng-click' => "navigate({{month.date.format('MMM')}})"}
```

This will produce this identically :

```
%li{'ng-click' => "navigate(02)"}
```

Yet, the first example will never work. How can I add a dynamic variable and also have Angular's click handler respond to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just lose the curly braces:

```
%li{'ng-click' => "navigate(month.date.format('MMM'))"}
```

Comment: Ah perfect! Thanks Joseph. Silly syntax ;D